# How can i search for a string in all the files in a directory ? I'm getting out of memory exception

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have two methods i call in the form1 constructor:

```
DirSearch(@"D:\C-Sharp");
SearchInFiles();
```

The DirSearch method:

```
public static void DirSearch(string sDir)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sDir))
                {
                    foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(d))
                    {
                        files.Add(f);
                    }
                    DirSearch(d);
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception excpt)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(excpt.Message);
            }
        }
```

And the SearchInfiles method:

```
private void SearchInFiles()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
            {
                string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(files[i]);
                for (int x = 0; x < lines.Length; x++)
                {
                    if (lines[x].Contains("setting"))
                    {
                        filesContent.Add(lines[x]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I'm getting exception out of memory on the line:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(files[i]);
```

How can i make the search faster if it's possible and how can i avoid this exception ?

Maybe i need to somehow make that it will not search for example in dll files and other files that are not editable only files like *.cs and *.txt how can i do it ?

Comment: I'd use a `StreamReader` and `using` statements to ensure everything is disposed of correctly in your loop. `Directory.GetFiles()` has an overload to specify search patterns, such as `"*.cs"` but I don't believe there's a way to specify multiple file types, I think you'll have to make multiple calls and append the files to your list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How can i make the search faster if it's possible and how can i avoid this exception ?

The line:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(files[i]);
```

Does "what it says on the tin" - it reads every line from an entire file (in to memory). For very large files, this will take a lot of memory.

The way to avoid this is to *not* load every line into memory all at once, but to stream the file into memory line-by-line.

```
using(var streamReader sr = new StreamReader(files[i]))
{
    string line;
    while((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
          if (line.Contains("setting"))
          {
              filesContent.Add(line);
          }
    }
}
```

Note that if using .NET 4 or greater this becomes much simpler with [`File.ReadLines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
foreach(var line in File.ReadLines(files[i]))
{
  ....
}
```

> Maybe i need to somehow make that it will not search for example in dll files and other files that are not editable only files like *.cs and *.txt how can i do it ?

You do that part by supplying a searchPattern to a [`GetFiles` overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(d,"*.txt"))
....
```

There does not appear to be a way to supply multiple file extensions, but you could simply chain together 2 lists

```
// all txt or cs files
var files = Directory.GetFiles(d,"*.txt").Concat(Directory.GetFiles(d,"*.cs"));
foreach(var f in files)
    ....
```

Comment: Just loop on [File.ReadLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: to filter multiple file exensions you could use:

Answer (score 3):

A) Instead of first getting all files and then process them all, process the file as soon as it is found.

So instead of the `files.Add` in your DirSearch, call SearchInFile with the file you found as parameter.

B) Don't read all lines in the file (they *are* text files, aren't they?), but use [`File.ReadLines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503(v=vs.110).aspx) to process the line as soon as it is read, so you can forget it if it doesn't match.

```
foreach(string line in File.ReadLines(theFile))
{
   // test the "line"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Not only are you reading all lines into memory at once, but you are looking at every file that exists in the directories.

This could be a problem.  For example, what if one of the files was some data file that was greater than 2 gigs?  Then you would have memory issues.

How about when you add the file in the files list, you also check to make sure the file is of the type you would want.

For example.

```
foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(d))
{
    if(f.Contains(".txt") || f.Contains(".cs"))
         files.Add(f);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why put all the names in list? It has to read the whole list before it starts processing the first.

Why read all the lines before processing?

```
public List<string> FindLines(string DirName)
{
    List<string> findLines = new List<string>();
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(DirName);
    if(di != null && di.Exists) 
    {
        foreach(FileInfo fi in di.EnumerateFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        {
            //Debug.WriteLine(fi.Extension);
            //Debug.WriteLine(fi.FullName);
            if (   string.Compare(fi.Extension, ".cs",   true) == 0 
                || string.Compare(fi.Extension, ".txt",  true) == 0
                || string.Compare(fi.Extension, ".text", true) == 0)
            {
                //findLines.Add(fi.FullName);
                using (StreamReader sr = fi.OpenText())
                {
                    string s = "";
                    while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        if (s.Contains("setting"))
                            findLines.Add(s);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return findLines;
}
```

Comment: @Sharondohp Sharonas This is faster than the accepted answer and less memory.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is reading all lines into memory all at once.

You should use a stream to read the file, or read a line at a time.